# Want to restrict a user from creating more than 10 records w/o RSF

Tags: validation, sobject

I have a object where 1 user can only create 10 record not more that that. If I don't want to code (by count() we can achieve it) but is there any other way that we can count the number of records no master detail relationship (role up summery) is there any other way we can solve this issue. please guide me the best way by which I can do it.

Comment: 10 records at a time or 10 records in total for the object?

Comment: You probably would need to write a before trigger on that object. If you dont want to use count, then just query for records owned by that user and check the size of the list. This might work if you are inserting one record at a time only, doing a bulk insert might turn out to a bit tricky

Comment: A controller extension would allow him to query on the UserID for record count on the object for using either records with the same createdbyID or OwnerID (depending on whether it matters) before allowing a Save operation. But, you're going to get into doing some kind of counting esp if there's more than one record that allowed to be created at a time.

Comment: @Prady that'd make a fine answer :-)

Comment: I think @crmprogdev has the better answer because this is a better UX. In the before insert trigger scenario, the user finds out after he/she has already entered info about the whole record, rather than at the beginning of the process after clicking New.

Comment: Yes agreed, but the OP is not specifying visualforce and likely wants as less code as possible as the real question is how to solve this without code.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I don't quite follow. How does writing a BeforeTrigger solve this without writing any code? The question is worded a bit vaguely and no clarification was ever provided even though it was requested.

Answer (score 1):

Please find following code i think this could be useful for you.

This code restrict user to create more than 99 records in a month. You can modify this trigger accordingly.

```
trigger MaxCases on Case (before insert) {
    Integer maxCases = null;
    CaseSettings__c settings = CaseSettings__c.getValues('default');

    if (settings != null) {
        maxCases = Integer.valueOf(settings.MaxCases__c);
    }

    if (maxCases != null) {
        Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id, Integer> caseCountMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();

        for (Case c: trigger.new) {
            userIds.add(c.OwnerId);
            caseCountMap.put(c.OwnerId, 0);
        }

        Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([
            select Name
            from User
            where Id in :userIds
        ]);

        for (AggregateResult result: [
            select count(Id),
                OwnerId
            from Case
            where CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH and
                OwnerId in :userIds
            group by OwnerId
        ]) {
            caseCountMap.put((Id) result.get('OwnerId'), (Integer) result.get('expr0'));
        }

        for (Case c: trigger.new) {
            caseCountMap.put(c.OwnerId, caseCountMap.get(c.OwnerId) + 1);

            if (caseCountMap.get(c.OwnerId) > maxCases) {
                c.addError('Too many cases created this month for user ' + userMap.get(c.OwnerId).Name + '(' + c.OwnerId + '): ' + maxCases);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source : - [Link](https://gist.github.com/pcon/8afe91eee8fde2d0fd15)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative - requiring no code to write

Install the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) open source package from GitHub, written by esteemed SFSE contributor Andrew Fawcett

This can count the # of child objects and save in a parent object field of type number.

Then, using a validation rule on the parent object, if the count > 10, throw validation error.

All point and click. No code

One caveat -- if you clone the parent object, the child count field will get cloned as well as it is not a true SFDC on-demand RSF field so you'll need to clear it out in a workflow or just wait until the first child object upon the cloned record is created.

Comment: This wouldn't work on a per-user basis would it ?

Comment: Ah, I must have misunderstood the question -- if parent could have 50 children but no given user can create more than 10 of them. DLRS won't solve that use case -- I agree; need trigger or VF controller; if the problem was to limit the count of children to no more than 10, or that some set of users can't create the 11th child, then DLRS would work.